# How define this routes in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am beginner in asp.net mvc.

I have 2 Controllers:

**HomeController actions:** index,about

url that i need:

```
  index action url: mydomain

  about action url: mydomain/about
```

**OtherController actions:** index

```
  index action url: mydomain/other
```

**MyCode That not works**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Other",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Other", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );

  routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Home Controller, to hit

```
index action url: mydomain
```

you need

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Home",
 url: "",
 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

to hit

```
about action url: mydomain/about
```

you need

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Home",
 url: "about",
 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

For your Other Controller, to hit

```
index action url: mydomain/other
```

you need

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Other",
 url: "other",
 defaults: new { controller = "Other", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note that, in all cases, the "name" parameter doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed `{controller}` in your `Default` routing spec.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: not missed, it for avoid duplicate url - also only with your solution its not works for url that i write above